# reload div tag jquery execute java code

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp form which includes a div `<div id="manufacturerContent"></div>`.  I wrote a jquery to reload manufacturerContent.jsp as below.  It reload the page fine, however inside manufacturerContent.jsp I notice it doesn't execute java code ie `<% System.out.println("test") %>` everytime i do a refresh.  I just want to reload the div without refreshing entire page.

```
function loadData() {
    $('#manufacturerContent').load('manufacturer-content-div.jsp', function() {

    });                                             
}
```

Comment: you need to source the data from a servlet or some other web service, not from the current `jsp`

Comment: When on earth will people stop being taught to put java code into `jsp` - this is so last century